# Where is MySQL Workbench Database Migration Wizard?

Tags: mysql, migration, mysql-workbench

I am using MySql 5.5 with MySql Workbench 5.2 CE. I have read that workbench has data migration feature (http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/migration/), but I am not able to find this feature in workbench.

Please tell me Where is MySQL Workbench Database Migration Wizard?

Update:

In Database menu there is only these three options.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my MySQL Workbench 5.2.43 CE it's available in **Database** menu. 
Option in menu is just **Migrate** and its avaliable with or without connection to database.

My exact version is:

5.2.43 CE for Windows, 
installed from file `

> mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.43-win32.msi (27 544 576 bytes)

On my Windows 7 have also installed XAMPP with MySQL 5.5.27, but I shouldnt matter.

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: Answer updated.